# Reference: K-theory of real Grassmann manifolds

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Was the complex K-theory of the unoriented real Grassmann manifold $G_{\mathbb{R}}(k,n)$ computed somewhere, at least for certain values of $k,n$?